# Why unnamed semaphore doesn't change when used in shared memory?

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory, semaphore

I have to make 2 processes (server/client) that can access the same shared memory. I send the keys of shared memory via UNIX sockets between the server and the client. Then, I create the shared memory segment, and use unnamed semaphores to sychronize the server/client. As I think, I do everything right, but when I run the client process I can see that the semaphore isn't even initialized!

server.c sample:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

sem_t *semaphore;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

//...making the connections here
// M is the number of semaphores i will use
    key_t key3;
    int shmid3;
    if ((shmid3 = shmget(key3, M*sizeof(sem_t), 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
      perror("shmget3");
      exit(1);
    }
    key3 = htonl(key3);
        if (send(s2, (const char*)&key3, 4, 0) == -1) {
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
    }
    int i;
    semaphore=(sem_t *)shmat(shmid3, (void *) 0, 0);
    if (semaphore == (sem_t *)(-1)) perror("shmat");
    for(i=0;i<M;i++) if(sem_init(&semaphore[i], 1, 1)!=0) perror("sem_init");
//..do some stuff...
    sleep(3);

    for(i=0;i<M;i++) sem_destroy( &semaphore[i] );
    if (shmdt(semaphore) == -1) {
      perror("shmdt");
      exit(1);
    }
    shmctl(shmid3, IPC_RMID, NULL);
//close connection...
}
```

client.c sample:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

sem_t *semaphore;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

//...making the connections here
// M is the number of semaphores i will use
    key_t key3;
    n = recv(s, &key3, 4, 0);
        if (n < 0) {
           perror("recv");
        }
        key3 = ntohl(key3); 
    int shmid3;
    if ((shmid3 = shmget(key3, M*sizeof(sem_t), 0644 )) == -1) {
      perror("shmget3");
      exit(1);
    }

    semaphore=(sem_t *)shmat(shmid3, (void *) 0, 0);
    if (semaphore == (sem_t *)(-1)) perror("shmat");

    int value;
    sleep(1); 
    sem_getvalue(&semaphore[0], &value); 
    printf("\n[%d]\n",value); //always prints 0

    //...do stuff...
    if (shmdt(semaphore) == -1) {
  perror("shmdt");
  exit(1);
}
//close connection...
}
```

There isn't something wrong with the UNIX connection because I share and other memory segments, and they work just fine. I also tried changing the `pshared` argument of `sem_init`but still nothing changes in the client.
I actualy want to use the semaphores in clinet's threads(M), but I see that they do not initialize even in the main process.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have any special reason to be using System V shared memory instead of the (in my opinion) simpler mmap interface?

Comment: ① You don't initialize the shm key — how do you know it's not initialized to IPC_PRIVATE? ② You don't check sem_getvalue for errors — how do you know it's not ENOSYS or EINVAL?

Comment: Using sleep(1) does not completely guarantee that there's no race between the client and the server...

Comment: @NothingsImpossible yes I have to use System V shared memory acording to my excercise.

Comment: @pilcrow here yes, but I had put and sem_getvalue in if!=0 condition and it didn'd bothered...

Comment: @bazza I just use sleep here to be sure that the client will reach the sem_getvalue after the server will have initialize the semaphore

Comment: @pilcrow You were right! I checked if the key was IPC_PRIVATE and it was... Thank you a lot! I am new here so I don't know how to promote your comment to the answer of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Adapting from troubleshooting in the comments...)

The uninitialized `key_t key3` happens to be initialized to the value IPC_PRIVATE, which means that a new shared memory segment is created for each caller of shmget().  The key should be explicitly initialized (in this case as by ftok()).